# AngularJS execute after render with ng-switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've created an ng-switch that hides and shows "pages", for some of the elements I require a jQuery selector function to be ran. But because Angular destroys and creates the elements for rendering, I need a method of reapplying this jquery selector function.

My first attempt was just to include a  tag inside the element, but it only executes it the first time the page gets rendered.

UPDATE:

HTML:

```
<wizard-step ng-switch-when="customer">
    <h1>Customer Details</h1>

    <div class="step-content">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group float-label-control">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" ng-model="currentCase.customer.first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group float-label-control">
                <label for="">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group float-label-control">
                <label for="">Textarea</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Textarea" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="previousStep()" value="&laquo; Pending Cases " class="btn btn-warning" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="nextStep()" value="Products &raquo;" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>

    <script>
        if (window.jQuery) {
            $('.float-label-control').floatLabels();
        }
        console.log('float trigger');
    </script>
</wizard-step>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.float-label-control').floatLabels();
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if we could see some code. Do you want the jquery selector function to be run every time the ng-switch changes?

Comment: If you need to access some DOM elements you need to use a directive to do so, it will eliminate this problem since the directive will be reprocessed whenever angular sees it in the DOM

Comment: Can you link to the floatLabels javascript function you're using as well I found a floatlabel library but it appears to use a different syntax

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/float-label-pattern-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to work on the textarea but otherwise I used the code here:

http://clubdesign.github.io/floatlabels.js/

to create this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DH3zdvoCwAFOxc4pahkI?p=preview

Key parts are define a directive:

```
directive("floatLabels", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link:function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
      iElem.floatlabel()
      console.log(iElem)
    }
  }
})
```

Apply that directive:

```
<input
   type="text"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Last Name"
   float-labels/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the code below works, but let me explain the reasoning behind it.
As shaunhusain mentioned in the comments, if you create a directive and place it INSIDE the ng-switch, it will be processed AFTER the ng-switch. So now you have a way of knowing that your jquery is getting executed after the ng-switch has been processed. Your directive will probably want to transclude some markup so you are not restricted to the same template every time.

Now to create the directive: (there is probably a typo or two, but I hope it helps!)

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="step-content">' + '<form role="form">' + '<div ng-transclude></div>' + '</form>' + '</div>',
        ,
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            $('.float-label-control').floatLabels();
        }
    };
});


<myDirective>

<div class="form-group float-label-control">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" ng-model="currentCase.customer.first_name">
</div>
<div class="form-group float-label-control">
    <label for="">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group float-label-control">
    <label for="">Textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Textarea" rows="1"></textarea>
</div>

</myDirective>
```